# Making new data frame in R

Tags: r

Say, I have a data table with three columns: apples, orange, and age.
What code I can write in R to make the other one with upper case: FRUITS, AGE, USE

| apple | orange | age |  |  | FRUITS | AGE | USE |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 3 | 2 | 1-3 | - | - | apple | 1-3 | 3 |
| 4 | 5 | 4-6 | - | - | apple | 4-6 | 4 |
| 8 | 9 | 7-9 | - | - | apple | 7-9 | 8 |
|  |  |  | - | - | orange | 1-3 | 2 |
|  |  |  | - | - | orange | 4-6 | 5 |
|  |  |  | - | - | orange | 7-9 | 9 |

This is an example so I gives fewer values, but let's say my data have 30 rows like that. I do not want to manually add each rows into a new data frame. how can I turn the apples and oranges into FRUITS and make a column use?

Comment: see `tidy::pivot_longer()`

Answer (score 0):

I think using the pivot_longer() tidy function moodymudskipper suggested it would be coded like this

```
library(tidyr)
new_data <- data %>%
pivot_longer(!age, names_to = "FRUITS", values_to = "USE")%<%
select_all(toupper)
```

Answer (score 0):

One possible way to solve your problem

```
library(data.table)

melt(as.data.table(df), 
     measure=c("apple", "orange"), 
     variable.name="FRUITS", 
     value.name="USE")
```